# Matlab multiple graph types inside one graph

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, mesh

I have a task to draw electrostatic field between
two electrodes( at given sizes and shape ),
what i have now is that i draw the electrodes with area plot (area(elect_x,elect_y))
the graph looks like this:

```
------------------.---
                  |..
     .---.        |..
     |...|        |..
.----....|        |..
|........|        |..
----------------------
```

and now i would need to draw inside this probably a mesh, showing the field.
Is there any way to do it, or i´m on a wrong way?
Thank you very much for every guide

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to overlay multiple plots in the same axes, type

```
hold on
```

before you plot the second graph (or set the `'NextPlot'` property of the axes to `'add'`), so that the first plot is not erased when the second one is drawn.

To show electrical field, you may want to have a look at [quiver](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/quiver.html), so you can visualize both direction and strength of the fiels. Also check out is [demo of quiver](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/quivdemo.html) to get and idea how you could show field strength with colors.

Comment: Hi, i have been experimenting with quiver and i found it really useful, but now i´m stuck because i have no idea, how to describe my electrodes as a 3D function, i know, its rather a mathematical problem now but i would be grateful for any answer or guide for this